# Printing only 6 and 10 charcters words in a linux file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

This is my file:

```
$cat filename  
10023a,vija45,8877au,qwer65,guru12 0099888das,baburam123,ganeshan1,feild55512
```

What I tried to do is using the sed below command to get the output to be only  6 charcters words in that file

```
sed  -ne 's/[a-z][0-9]\{6}/&/p' filename
```

it displaying all words and lines

Could you please any one help me on this..

**Expected output is**

```
vija45           baburam123  
8877au           ganeshan1   
qwer65           feild55512  
guru12
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: use grep `grep -o '\b[a-z][0-9]\{6\}\b' file`

Comment: Your regular expression matches one letter followed by 6 digits. Is that what you meant to match?

Comment: You need to match word boundaries. Otherwise, a regular expression for a 6 character word will match the first 6 characters in a longer word.

Comment: Please update your question using the proper format. Otherwise it is unclear how the output should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that:

```
tr "," "\n" <file | grep '^.\{6\}$\|^.\{10\}$'
```

First `tr` replaces all `,` with newlines, that we have each segment between the commas in a line.

Then `grep` searches for 6 or 10 character long lines and prints them.

With your given example, the output would then be:

```
10023a
vija45
8877au
qwer65
baburam123
feild55512
```

If `guru12 0099888das` must also be matched as a 6 character and a 10 character word, then just change the `tr` part to include also spaces:

```
tr ", " "\n" <file | grep '^.\{6\}$\|^.\{10\}$'
```

Comment: Thanks , can we change the output format to separate 6charcters are in different line and 10charcters in other line

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use grep for matching.

```
grep -o '\b\w\{6\}\b' file
```

Comment: or `'\b[a-zA-Z0-9]\{6\}\b'`

Comment: Thanks Man its working, would it be possible to get the same out put by using sed or Awk ..

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '
# keep only 6 char word (and space) by removing less or more than 6 character word
 s/.*/,&,/
 s/[^[:space:],]\{11,\}//g;s/[[:space:],][^[:space:],][[:space:],]\{1,5\}/,/g;s/[[:space:],][^[:space:],][[:space:],]\{7,9\}/,/g
# clean space element
 s/[[:space:],]\{2,\}/,/g;s/^[[:space:],]*//g;s/[[:space:],]*$//g
# remove empty line
 /$[[:space:],]*$/d
# 1 word per line (optional)
 y/ ,/\n\n/
' YourFile
```

Detail:

- print all word of 6 letter find in lines (option for 1 word printed per output line)
- self explained
- adapted for `,` separated

*Correction*: forget some `g` and a small bug on small word removing and add 10 char word (take 6 only in first version)

Comment: After using that whole commands getting below output 

[a,vija45,8877au,qwer65,guru12
baburam123,ganeshan1,feild55512]

Comment: sorry forget some `g` and the remove of small word also remove good one, correction made in script

Comment: Thanks @NeronLeVelu , would it be possible to get above my expected result by using awk or sed .. please help me